# Removing percentage of total from Google Analytics custom reports without losing other data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, traffic

My company is attempting to send scheduled custom referral traffic reports to some of our affiliates and we would very much like to hide/remove the "% of total" values that are appended below visits and transactions so that our affiliates don't have to know what our total site visits and transactions are.
I tried changing the report type from "explorer" to "flat table" but then I don't get the summary of all the pages that I need.

[here is a link to an image that better explains my question](http://postimg.org/image/xbv3xc0nf/)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment but since I can't do that yet I'll post here.

Google offers an API where you can pull the data from analytics and write your own code to process/present it. I know that might be a drastic change but it does offer you the freedom of presenting whatever data you like in whatever form you like. Maybe that could be interesting?

Comment: For future readers: I don't know if I'm allowed to post links here. If not, feel free to let me know and I'll remove it.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide